# Laravel one-to-Many and belongsTo Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have `Order` Table and `Booking` Table
A relation between `Order` Table and `Booking` Table is saved in 'order_bookings` Table

I want to fetch Order from the Booking Table

My Booking Model

```php
class Booking extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function order(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class,'order_bookings','booking_id','order_id');
    }

}
```

My Order Model

```php
class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'orders';
    protected $guarded = []; 

    public function bookings(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Booking::class,'order_bookings','order_id','booking_id');
    }
}
```

I am able to fetch all the bookings to an Order

How to fetch Order from a Booking Model?

`belongsTo` Not working

Comment: The opposite of `belongsToMany()` is `belongsToMany()`. `order_booking` looks like a `pivot` table between `orders` and `bookings`, and if you have a `pivot` table, you have `many-to-many`. Check the doumentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Can I get only first record from belongstomany ` $booking->order?->first()->delivery_address`. Since there will one Order associated with booking

Comment: Yes! You'd want to call the relationship `orders`, as a `many-to-many` should return 0 or more, then you'd do `$booking->orders?->first()?->delivery_address`. `->orders` would return a `Collection`, which you then chain `->first()`, and so on

Comment: Yes it is working thanks, I need to rename function order to orders. Should the function name  in prural?

Comment: The function name should always use a case that matches what it returns. A `hasOne()` and `belongsTo()` would be `order` (singular, since it can only return an `Order`, or `null`). `hasMany()` and `belongsToMany()` should be `orders`, since both of those can return multiple. Same goes for basic functions; if you return an Array, it would be plural. If you return a single value, singular. It's so you can read the method name and discern it's return from that. If you have a method called `orders` that only returns a single `Order`, it's not obvious and you might make incorrect assumptions 

Comment: `$booking->orders->first()->name` would trigger an exception if `orders` only returned a single `Order`. Similarly, `$booking->order->name` would trigger a different exception if `order` returned a `Collection` of `Order`s. Also, `$booking->orders->name` doesn't make sense at a glance; `orders` is plural, so _which_ name is it trying to reference? And `$booking->order->first()->name` doesn't make much sense either; why do you need `->first()` if there's only 1 `Order`? Plenty of other examples too, so yeah, naming the method properly is important for "obvious" usage 

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table implies that there is a many-to-many relation between orders and bookings. If that's the case, you need to use **belongsToMany()** instead of **belongsTo()** in the Booking model.

```
public function order() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class,'order_bookings','booking_id','order_id');
}
```